# Sping: @Autowired vs. Constructor injection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, nullpointerexception

I have 1 simple Repository

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    Optional<User> findUserByUsername(String username);
}
```

1 basic entity User with 2 fields, getters, setters

1 Service

```
@Service
public class UserPrincipalDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepository.findUserByUsername(username);
        User user = optionalUser.orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Not found username"));

        return new UserPrincipal(user);
    }
}
```

My question is: When I used @Autowired, this loadUserByUserName() function works as intended but when I do a constructor injection for the UserRepository, it throws a NullPointerException?

```
@Service
public class UserPrincipalDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserPrincipalDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepository.findUserByUsername(username);
        User user = optionalUser.orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Not found username"));

        return new UserPrincipal(user);
    }
}
```

Have anyone faced the same situation?

**UPDATE**: No clue why when I try again 1 day after, it runs normally.
The NullPointerException didn't show in the console but it shows when I do debugging.

Comment: Where does it throw the NPE? Is the `userRepository` null, or the `optionalUser`?
Does this perhaps occur in a test? If so, have you maybe mocked the `userRepository` and not met a capturing condition (in which case `findUserByUsername` would return null instead of `Optional.empty()`)?

Comment: Add `@Autowired` to the constructor.

Comment: The field cannot be `null` else the application would fail to start. So either you are creating an instance yourself (outside the scope of Spring) or this isn't the actual code that you are using and some AOP leads to invoking it on the proxy instead of delegating it to the actual underlying object.

Comment: Take a look at lombok's `@RequiredArgsConstructor` annonation. As for me, it works well when you declare your dependencies as `private final` members.

Comment: I forgot to update, it didn't print out to the console.
When I debug it at the `userRepository.findUserByUsername(username);` it can't get through that line.

Comment: Adding `@Autowired` won't help, nor will adding lombok annotations. So my guess is still that you aren't showing the code you are actual using (either you still have a default constructor, or a method is `final`). But without you showing the actual code instead of some dumbed down version this is impossible to answer.

Comment: this is actually my actual code...